# Is there any scripting support on Windows Phone?

Tags: python, perl, windows-phone-7, powershell, smartphone

In Windows Mango OS , is there any scripting environment that is supported?

Does it have support for powershell or python or perl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be off-topic here, but there is a way to do in-the-phone scripting. The [TouchDevelop](http://www.touchdevelop.com/) app lets you do pretty cool stuff.

If you your question refers to using a scripting language to make apps, then the answer would be NO.

Comment: TouchDevelop is JUST about to retire in like a week :-(

Answer (score 6):

WP7 does not have Python support, or perl / powershell. See the IronPython request here:

http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/26534

You can use JavaScript within a `WebBrowser` control.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Powershell in the service layer, adding System.Management.Automation and Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility to the service project.

Comment: which project? could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

There's no official scripting environment for WP7, but there's a working port of IronRuby (although I've never tried it): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff960707.aspx